# Azure API Management policy caching of JWKs for JWT validation

Tags: azure, validation, jwt, azure-api-management, azure-policy

I'm trying to implement caching of public key provided by `openid-configuration/jwks` endpoint of our JWT provider. I want to use cached value for validation of signature of incoming request. We want to have cache in place in order to lower requesting jwks endpoint. So we decided to create custom APIM policy in order to do that. After few hours of struggles I found myself clueless. Therefore I would like to address some questions about APIM xml policies.

1. How can I read request JWTs `kid` or `x5t` in policy? Regarding to [APIM policy expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions) calling `AsJwt()` returns `Jwt` object which does not contains `Header` property which should contain required fields

   - I tryed `Id`, `Claims` with no successful reach of `kid` or `x5t` (`<set-variable name="requestKid" value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization","").Split(' ')[1].AsJwt()?.____)"/>`)
2. When retrieving JWKs from the provider endpoint I'm not able to store various fields of response into separate context variables, it always fails on second `<set-variable`. Seems like `(IResponse)context.Variables["jwksResponse"])` is null when calling second time. Does context variables get destroyed after first read?

```
<send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="jwksResponse" timeout="10" ignore-error="true">
  <set-url>https://some.identity.server/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks</set-url>
  <set-method>GET</set-method>
</send-request>
<set-variable name="jwksn" value="@(((IResponse)context.Variables["jwksResponse"]).Body.As<JObject>()["keys"][0]["n"])" />
<set-variable name="jwkse" value="@(((IResponse)context.Variables["jwksResponse"]).Body.As<JObject>()["keys"][0]["e"])" />
```

3. How can I set key exponent and modulus attributes? When I use variables from previous step I got xml validation Error: `"ValidationError" - "Error in element 'validate-jwt' on line 8, column 4: value is not a valid base64url string."` while It works when when hardcoded. (I also tried hacks with `Convert.ToBase64String()`, with no success, to me seems like xml validator issue - can it be overriden?)

```
<issuer-signing-keys>
  <key e="@((string)context.Variables["jwkse"])" n="@((string)context.Variables["jwksn"])"/>
</issuer-signing-keys>
```

4. Can I use `x5c` value retrieved from our JWKs provider as key value? like so:

```
<issuer-signing-keys>
  <key>@((string)context.Variables["jwksx5c"])</key>
</issuer-signing-keys>
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you can't use OpenID support in validate-jwt policy? It will cache JWKs internally.

Comment: @VitaliyKurokhtin what is caching with OpenId like? Is there some documentation about caching jwks keys on apim policy? I haven't found anything regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

After further investigation we found [gitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/63118) thread regarding caching of JWKs when using JWT validation with OpenId. It seems JKWs are cached for 1 hour and also recached when validation fails. However this behavior is not stated in documentation.